# Emacs word search

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I search in documents I almost always need to use exact-word search, so I do a lot of `C-s`, `M-s w` key combinations to enter I-search mode first, then to toggle word mode on.

Is there a way to turn on word mode by default in I-search mode so that the search starts in exact-word mode - and preferably an `M-s w` would only be necessary to turn off word mode?

Thanks, 
Ben

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to hit `C-s` first. **`M-s w`** does word search. It is bound to `isearch-forward-word`, and you can bind it to another key if you don't want to use `M-s w`.

(And if you want nonincremental search then use `M-s w RET`.)

This is all explained in the Emacs manual, node [Word Search](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Word-Search.html). You can get to that in Emacs using `C-h r i word search`.